# Connecting to github via ssh, times out without response

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, internet-connection, github

When I try to connect via SSH to GitHub from my Ubuntu 22.04 server (i just want to pull from a private repository) I get timeout.

I've seen similar questions to mine but non of the possible solutions worked for me.

Pinging to github.com works properly.

I've tried to run `ssh -vT git@github.com` and this is all I get:

```
user@server:~/.ssh$ ssh -vvvT git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matche                                                          d no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/root/.ssh/known_ho                                                          sts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/root/.ssh/known_h                                                          osts2'
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.4] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
(Stays here until timeout)
```

From my Windows Desktop (that is in the same network) I get `Hi <my username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

I added the public key from .ssh folder to github. I even tried to use the same key my Windows PC uses without any luck.

I tried to connect to the 443 port like it's suggested on similar discussions but It behaves the same way.

I disabled the firewall and I still get the same errors.

Comment: Just to be clear, you shouldn't add your private SSH key (`.ssh/id_rsa`) to Github, but rather your public key (`.ssh/id_rsa.pub`). Anyway, what happens if you use the flag `-o IPQoS=none` in your `ssh` command above?

Comment: Thank you for answering, It works with your flag! Does It mean I have QoS Policies defined in my system by default? What does it imply and what actions should I take?

Comment: I've set my ssh_config to ignore IPQoS with IPQos none. I tried disableing my routers QoS to test it and the issue was still happening, so I'm guessing it has something to do with my server.

Comment: If it _had_ worked, then it would have implied that your router (usually it's the router) had some completely broken handling for "new style" (i.e. post-1998) DSCP QoS markings. (When OpenSSH switched from ToS to DSCP a few years ago, it actually uncovered a few things like VMware completely failing to handle such packets...)

Comment: Have you reloaded/restarted your ssh daemon after changing the config?

Comment: Sorry I think my message earlier didn't make it clear "I've set my ssh_config to ignore IPQoS with IPQos none." did in fact work.  I was still trying to understand the issue.
My aplogies, I'm quite excited since I've been having issues with this for a few days and now you found the cause of the issue

Comment: @CarlesFitóNegre Good to hear. You should post the solution as the answer and accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the command with `-o IPQoS=none` solved the issue in my particular case. I edited `ssh_config` and added the line `IPQoS none`, this way it will always perform ssh without Quality of Service.

Comment: Still times out, in my case :(